# Setting a array from post to public array

Tags: php, jquery, http-post, json

I have some trouble with my script

the problem is that if I have a json array which I get through post and I would like to
set it to public array so that i can use it outside of my function.
Here is my code.

Html Code:

```
<input name="myValue">
```

Jquery Code:

```
var myArray = newArray(); 

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('input[name="myValue"]').foucusout(function(){
     var postValue = $(this).val();
     $.post('myPhp.php',{post:postValue},function(data){

      var JsonArray = $.parseJSON(data);
          myArray = JsonArray;
     };

}):
```

PHP Code;

```
<?

if(isset($_POST["post"])){

$myVal = $_POST["post"];

$db = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parts WHERE code = '$myVal'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($db);

echo json_encode($result); 
}    
?>
```

This is not setting myArray. 
What am i doing wrong?

*Edit*

Jquery Code:

```
var myArray = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(e) {


   $('input[name=myValue]').focusout(function(e) {
        var myPost = $(this).val();
        $.post('myPhp.php',{part:myPost},function(data){
                myArray = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(myArray[2]);
            });
    });

    $('button[name=getArrayValue]').on("click",function(){
            alert(myArray[3]);
        });
});
```

HTML Code

```
<input name="myValue">
<button name="getArrayValue">Get</button>
```

When i focusout out the input field i get the alert whit my second value from array and when i press the button i get the value from my third array position.
so it's working now.

Thanks every body for your help.

Comment: You're using a deprecated library and a sql-injection vulnerable code

Comment: Any errors in the console? Any PHP errors? Are you sure the MySQL query is actually selecting something?

Comment: You don't even connect to the DB before querying it.

Comment: i get the data to my jquery, if i alert JsonArry inside post i see the data that i get from php but if i alert myArray outside postfuncrion i get undefined.

Comment: And _where_ did you put that alert statement resp. _when_ are you calling it ...?

Comment: $.post('myPhp.php',{post:postValue},function(data){

      var JsonArray = $.parseJSON(data);
          myArray = JsonArray; alert(JsonArray[0]); is showing the value from data base;

Answer (score 0):

You don't connect to the database before you are querying it. How could the query select something if you did not connect to a database?

Add this before your query:

```
$username = //your DB username
$password = //your DB password

mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
```

You really should use a non-deprecated API, such as PDO or MySQLi.

**Edit:**

It's quite simple: the AJAX call is asynchronous, so the array gets set after the focusout handler is run. This is what happens on focusout:

1. The focusout handler gets called
2. You tell jQuery to make an AJAX call an supply a function which should be run when the AJAX request is finished.
3. The focusout handler finishes and tries to alert the **not yet set array**.
4. The AJAX request finishes and jQuery calls the function you supplied.
5. **Then the array is set, long after your focusout handler.**

Comment: that is not the proble i have that and i do get the array from php

Comment: Ah. How did you verify  that? @NamirDžilić

Comment: if i alert my JsonArray inside the post function i can see the data on my screen but if i alert myArray outside the foucusout function i get undefined. the real code is not vulnerable this is the simple version of the code. but i think this should set myArray to JsonArray.

Comment: Ah, now I know what's wrong. Let me make an edit. @NamirDžilić

Comment: I don't know what i did but its working now. I will add my code that i just made to source code.